# How do I align a bmatrix inside a tabularray?

Tags: tables, matrices, tabularray

**Edit**

The issue I described below [was a bug](https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/300) that was quickly fixed by the package author.

**Original Post**

The default baseline of a matrix is centered, here shown inside a `tabularray` table and using the augmented `+bmatrix` provided by that package:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr} { colspec={l c X[l]} }
    a &
    $\begin{+bmatrix}
        x \\ y \\ z
    \end{+bmatrix}$ &
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
    eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
    voluptua. \\
    b & $t$ \\
    c & $i$ & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed
    diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt. \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Which produces the following:

[image: default matrix alignment]

I would like the first row to all be aligned at the top. Using the `baseline` argument of the `bmatrix` has a surprising (to me) result.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr} { colspec={l c X[l]} }
    a &
    $\begin{+bmatrix}[baseline=T]
        x \\ y \\ z
    \end{+bmatrix}$ &
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
    eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
    voluptua. \\
    b & $t$ \\
    c & $i$ & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed
    diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt. \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image: matrix with changed baseline]

How can I get this alignment, without the extra vertical whitespace inside the matrix?

Comment: With the first code provided, you could change the colspec for the last column to `X[l,m]` so its middle aligns with the baseline, rather than its top. Or do you not like what that does to the third row?

Comment: Just noticed you wanted it all aligned at top. How about `\usepackage{nicematrix}` then `{ colspec={Q[l,t] c X[l,t]} }` then `\begin{bNiceMatrix}[baseline=t] ... \end{bNiceMatrix}`?

Comment: @frabjous, thanks! Replacing `+bmatrix` with `bNiceMatrix` and changing the `colspec` gives me the result I'm looking for.

I was _hoping_ to get everything done with just `tabularray`, but I'm not sure if that's possible.